# Multiple instances for a limited time frame

Tags: appharbor

I will be running a single instance full month, free normally. How will i be billed if I run a second instance 30 hours a month? Do you bill hourly? Or do I need to upgrade Catamaran to use a second instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only billed for the time that you actually consume resources and you don't have to change plans add extra workers. Just add the extra worker for the amount of time you need it, and you'll be billed for the time used.

Comment: Rune has already answered my question on support forum, but thanks again :)